# Configuring Custom Events with Spring Data REST for Specific CRUD Operations

Tags: spring, rest, logging, events

How can I configure Spring Data REST to trigger custom events when specific CRUD operations are performed on my entities? I want to perform some additional processing or logging when certain events occur, but I'm not sure how to hook into the Spring Data REST event system. Are there any examples or best practices for implementing custom events with Spring Data REST?